# IOIO Android cannot detect IOIO on 4.2.1 with debugging on

Tags: java, android, ioio

I am working on a IOIO project and I understand that the OS won't detect IOIO if you are using debugging on with 4.2.2 or greater due to secure debugging on a Nexus 4. I managed to downgrade it to 4.2.1 and the sample project works well with debugging on. So, I created my own project based on the IOIOSimpleApp and everything works fine. However, when I add more and more UI stuff to the activity, it stopped working with debug mode on, only works if it's AOA. Then I simply reverted everything back to IOIOSimple App, guess what, it still doesn't work.

So my issue is, what is the magic that happened that makes my project doesn't work on 4.2.1 on debug mode? I checked everything from the Manifest to every single detail. I even tried to put the IOIOService to my project, that doesn't solve the problem either.

My reason not to post any code is because I reverted all the code back to IOIOSimpleApp, you can grab it from their github. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the github issues list:

> Moreover, on Android >= 4.2.2, ADB mode will NOT work and you HAVE to
>   turn USB debugging off and use OpenAcessory or otherwise use
>   Bluetooth.

src: https://github.com/ytai/ioio/issues/91

Also you can use [IOIOBridge](https://github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki/IOIO-Bridge) if you want to debug your app while connected to the ioio board without bluetooth.

Comment: This does not address the question asked, which concerns 4.2.1 not 4.2.2